# Как Шляпник предлагаю перевести названия шляп

Tags: предложение, локализация, нет-в-transifex, новогодние-шляпы

[image: Шляпник]

Comment: кажется @alexolut этот вопрос поднимал, и кажется там есть технические трудности вроде того что они не в транзифексе. По-моему он на meta.stackexchange писал по этому поводу.

Comment: О да. Желаю удачи в переводе названия шляпы с Тако :)

Comment: @D-side дык это ж `Don't want to(wanna) talk about it`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я знаю что это, мне интересно, как решат задачу перевода этого на русский с сохранением каламбура :)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму [тыц](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34203312#34203312).

Comment: @alexolut, вот это в ответ наверное?)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму получите, распишитесь :)

Answer (score 5):

Подобное предложение было озвучено мной в чате:

> [надо бы еще названия шляп перевести. А то шляпно получилось со шляпами :)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34203302#34203302)

и даже получен ответ от менеджера сообщества:

> [Это нельзя, к сожалению, сделать.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34203312#34203312)